# quick sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, quicksort, insertion-sort

I have this working insertion sort javascript code.

```
Array.prototype.insertionSort = function() {  
  var A = this; 
  var time = 0;                                
  var n = A.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    var v = A[i];
    var j = i-1;
    while (j >= 0 && A[j] > v) {
      A[j+1] = A[j];
      j--; 
      var temp = new Array(this);
      setTimeout(callback(JSON.stringify(temp)), 500*(time++));
    }
    A[j+1] = v;
    var temp = new Array(this);
    setTimeout(callback(JSON.stringify(temp)), 500*(time++));
  }
  return time;
}
```

I need something similar for quciksort, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What's this `callback` your code refers to?  It isn't an argument to `insertionSort`, so it's clearly not being _used_ as a callback here.  My guess would be that it returns a function which prints the string when called.    


Regardless, there's no need for all that temporary array nonsense.  `callback(JSON.stringify(temp))` is executed immediately, and its _return value_ is the callback that gets passed to `setTimeout`.  Just calling `JSON.stringify(A)` without copying A would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the late posting, but I hope this may help somebody. QuickSort is a Divide and Conquer algorithm. It picks an element as pivot and partitions the given array around the picked pivot. You can select pivot in the following ways.
**a)pick the first element as the pivot(Implemented below) b)pick the last element as pivot c)Pick a random element as pivot.d)pick median as a pivot.**
if your array is already sorted then time complexity would be O(n^2) but for the average and best case it is O(N log N). It is in place algorithm and nonstable(as partitioning does one of the long-range exchanges). In some cases quicksort might take quadratic time. Quicksort has more overhead even for tiny arrays for sizes less than 10-20. If you use insertion sort for the small size of arrays then you might reduce the processing time by 15-20 %. Sharing my code below, also if you want to reduce more processing time then try to estimate partitioning element to be middle of an array.

```js
class QuickSort{
 constructor(){
  this.cutoff = 10;
 }
 partition(arr, lo, hi){
  let i = lo, j = hi+1;
  debugger;
  while(true){
   while(arr[++i] < arr[lo]) if(i == hi) break;
   while(arr[lo] < arr[--j]) if(j == lo) break;
   if(i >= j) break; 
   this.swap(arr, i, j);
  }
   this.swap(arr, lo, j);
   return j;
 }
 swap(arr, i, j){
  let temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
 }
 sort(arr, lo, hi){
  //if(hi <= lo) return;
  if((this.cutoff + lo) -1 >= hi){
   let insertionSort = new InsertionSort();
   insertionSort.sort(arr); return;  
  }
  console.log('Inside Quick Sort');
  let j = this.partition(arr, lo, hi);
  this.sort(arr, lo, j-1);
  this.sort(arr, j+1, hi);
 }
 shuffle(arr) {
  let n = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   // choose index uniformly in [0, i]
   let r =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
   this.swap(arr, i, r);
  }
  console.log('After uniform random Shuffle');
  console.log(arr);
  this.sort(arr, 0, n-1);
 }
}

class InsertionSort{
 constructor(){
  this.quickSort = new QuickSort();
 }
 sort(arr){
  console.log("Inside Insertion sort");
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
     for(let j = i; j > 0; j--){
   if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){
    this.quickSort.swap(arr, j, j-1);
   }
   }
   
  }    
 }
}

let arr = [101, 22,4,22,2,7,9,10,49,101,-1,4,1,6,99];
console.log('Before sorting an array');
console.log(arr);
let quickSort = new QuickSort();
quickSort.shuffle(arr);
console.log('After Sorting an array');
console.log(arr);
```

you can get to know the time complexity of from this post [time complexity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nVbJV5pZa8)

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article on Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is pretty thorough and even includes a few pseudocode implementations.

Wikipedia summarizes the problem like so:

> Quicksort is a divide and conquer algorithm. Quicksort first divides a
>   large array into two smaller sub-arrays: the low elements and the high
>   elements. Quicksort can then recursively sort the sub-arrays.
>
> The steps are:
>
> 1. Pick an element, called a pivot, from the array.
> 2. Partitioning: reorder the array so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way). After this partitioning, the pivot is in its final position. This is called the partition operation.
> 3. Recursively apply the above steps to the sub-array of elements with smaller values and separately to the sub-array of elements with greater values.
>
> The base case of the recursion is arrays of size zero or one, which are in order by definition, so they never need to be sorted.
>
> The pivot selection and partitioning steps can be done in several
>   different ways; the choice of specific implementation schemes greatly
>   affects the algorithm's performance.

And just a heads-up, I remember off-by-one errors being the biggest headache with this problem when I did it in school, so if you don't get the right answer right away, double-check your pivot selection and partitioning logic.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17751788)

Comment: @defghi1977 I was assuming that Wikipedia links are more likely to persist throughout my lifetime than SO, but you're right, I should have provided a summary of the linked article. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check google before posting a question: Quicksort is a very common algorithm and you have plenty of resources describing it.

```
function swap(items, firstIndex, secondIndex){
    var temp = items[firstIndex];
    items[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    items[secondIndex] = temp;
}


function partition(items, left, right) {

    var pivot   = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
        i       = left,
        j       = right;


    while (i <= j) {

        while (items[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (items[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            swap(items, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    return i;
}


function quickSort(items, left, right) {

    var index;

    if (items.length > 1) {

        left = typeof left != "number" ? 0 : left;
        right = typeof right != "number" ? items.length - 1 : right;

        index = partition(items, left, right);

        if (left < index - 1) {
            quickSort(items, left, index - 1);
        }

        if (index < right) {
            quickSort(items, index, right);
        }

    }

    return items;
}

// first call
var result = quickSort(items);
```

Code credits: [N.C.Zakas](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/)

Furthermore, note that Quicksort is used by V8 when calling **Array.prototype.sort()** on arrays > 10 items ([V8 source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L758)). On smaller arrays, InsertionShort is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

heres a short version of quick sort written in pure JS!

as seen in [Intro To Algorithms](https://mcdtu.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition-sep-2010.pdf)

```
var partition = function (arr, low, high) {
    var x = arr[high]
    var i = low - 1
    for (var j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= x) {
            i++
            var temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
        }
    }
    var temp = arr[i + 1]
    arr[i + 1] = arr[high]
    arr[high] = temp
    return i + 1 
}

var quickSort = function (arr, low, high) {
    if (low < high) {
        index = partition(arr,low,high)
        if (low < index-1) quickSort(arr,low,index-1)
        if (index+1 < high) quickSort(arr,index+1,high)
    }
}

var list2 = [1000,13,12,1001,82,1,2,4,3,0]

console.log(quickSort(list2,0,list2.length))
```

also on my [GitHub](https://github.com/dm20/Node-Structures/blob/master/Lists/generic%20helpers/quicksort.js)